# Removing the white spaces between the plots resulting from timetk library in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, time-series

I am trying to have very neat plots. So, trying to removes the whites spaces between the plots. I am using the `timetk` library. I have seen some of the examples related to the same questions, but those queries are mostly from [grid.arrange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32141400/remove-white-space-between-plots-and-table-in-grid-arrange)  or command `+theme(plot.margin = unit(c(-0.25,0.5,-0.25,0.5), "lines"))` from [ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66442496/how-to-reduce-the-vertical-white-space-between-plots-using-ggarrange-in-r)  library. These concepts do not work on some of the plots commands with timetk library.
When there will be many plots, I want to have very neet plots.

My codes are

```
library(tidyverse)
library(timetk)

    ## Case 1

walmart_sales_weekly %>%
    group_by(Store, Dept) %>%
    plot_anomaly_diagnostics(Date, Weekly_Sales,
                             .facet_ncol = 3, 
                             .interactive = TRUE)
```

[image: anomaly]

```
## Case 2

walmart_sales_weekly %>%
  select(Date, Weekly_Sales,Size, Temperature,Fuel_Price, CPI, Unemployment )%>%
  pivot_longer(-Date)%>%
    group_by(name) %>%
  plot_seasonal_diagnostics(.date_var =  Date, 
                              .value =  value, 
                              .feature_set = 'month.lbl', 
                              .facet_vars = name
                              )
```

[image: seasonal]

```
## Case 3

walmart_sales_weekly %>%
  select(Date, Weekly_Sales,Size, Temperature,Fuel_Price, CPI, Unemployment )%>%
  pivot_longer(-Date)%>%
    group_by(name) %>%
  plot_time_series(.date_var =  Date, 
                              .value =  value, 
                             .facet_ncol = 2, .smooth = FALSE
                              )
```

[image: timeseries_plot]

I required timeseries plots with tiketk library. I do not like to use any other library

[image: My requirement plots]

Answer (score 1):

This is related to how `plotly` produces facets. If you are trying to make neat plots, I suggest using `ggplot` by setting `.interactive = FALSE`. This will ensure the whitespace can be managed with `ggplot2`.

Once you have a `ggplot2` object, you can control the `theme()` function to adjust the spacing. See this Stack Overflow for more information. [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681647/ggplot-how-to-increase-spacing-between-faceted-plots)

```r
# Change spacing between facets on both axis
p + theme(panel.spacing = unit(2, "lines"))

# Change horizontal spacing between facets
p + theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(2, "lines"))

# Change vertical spacing between facets
p + theme(panel.spacing.y = unit(2, "lines"))
```

Comment: got it. perfect.